# to get an alert when it's strong buy both on current candle and last candle

Tags: pine-script

it's the technical ratings indicator and I want to find out how can I shoot an alert when the rating is strong buy on the current candle but it also has to be strong buy on the last candle

for example if the rating is sell right now but on the next candle it becomes strong buy, I don't want that, it should be strong buy last candle and strong buy current candle

I was on 1 hour chart, and this is what I tried. it kind of worked when I tested it but I'm a bit unsure about its accuracy

```
_lastbar = calcRatingStatusalert(ratingTotal_mtf1hA)[1] == "0"
_condblb1hsb = _lastbar and calcRatingStatusalert(ratingTotal_mtf1hA) == "0"
alertcondition(_condblb1hsb, "lb sb, 1h sb", "lb sb, 1h sb")
```

Comment: Can you edit and clarify your question ? Especially the meaning of your code : what did you try, what did you get, what did you want ?

Comment: I've edited it, hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a little mistake in your code, you should write :

```
_lastbar = calcRatingStatusalert(ratingTotal_mtf1hA[1]) == "0"
_condblb1hsb = _lastbar and calcRatingStatusalert(ratingTotal_mtf1hA) == "0"
alertcondition(_condblb1hsb, "lb sb, 1h sb", "lb sb, 1h sb")
```

The change is

```
calcRatingStatusalert(ratingTotal_mtf1hA)[1]
```

to

```
calcRatingStatusalert(ratingTotal_mtf1hA[1])
```